# Not able to read checked status of Custom Checkbox Server Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, custom-controls

I am not able to read the Checked status of my custom checkbox control.

I created this control so that it would rendor correctly for easy use with bootstrap.
The control renders perfectly, and I have all the function that I want/need EXCEPT being able to read the checked status of the input when the user clicks 'submit'.

## Custom Server Control Code (C#):

```
    public class InlineBootstrapCheckBox : CheckBox, IPostBackDataHandler, ICheckBoxControl
    {
        private string value;
        private string labelCSS;
        private string labelID;

        public string LabelID
        {
            get
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.labelID))
                {
                    return this.labelID;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                this.labelID = value;
            }
        }

        public string LabelCSS
        {
            get
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.labelCSS))
                {
                    return this.labelCSS;
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            set
            {
                this.labelCSS = value;
            }
        }

        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.value))
                {
                    return this.value;
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException("You must set a 'Value' for InlineBootstrapCheckBox Controls");
                }
            }

            set
            {
                this.value = value;
            }
        }

        protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(string.Format("<label id=\"{0}\" class=\"{1}\" for=\"{2}\">", (this.LabelID != null) ? this.LabelID : string.Concat(this.ID, "_Label"), (this.LabelCSS != null) ? string.Concat(this.LabelCSS, " checkbox-inline") : "checkbox-inline", this.ID));
            writer.WriteLine(string.Format("<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"{0}\" value=\"{1}\">", this.ID, this.Value));
            writer.WriteLine(this.Text);
            writer.WriteLine("</label>");
        }
    }
```

## Markup Code (.ASPX):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label id="lblCategories" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Categories</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <cookout:InlineBootstrapCheckBox runat="server" ID="chkRibs" Text="Ribs" Value="1" />
        <cookout:InlineBootstrapCheckBox runat="server" ID="chkChicken" Text="Chicken" Value="2" />
        <cookout:InlineBootstrapCheckBox runat="server" ID="chkBrisket" Text="Beef Brisket" Value="3" />
        <cookout:InlineBootstrapCheckBox runat="server" ID="chkPork" Text="Pork" Value="4" />
        <cookout:InlineBootstrapCheckBox runat="server" ID="chkAnythingBut" Text="Anything But" Value="5" />
    </div>
</div>
```

## Code Behind (C#):

### This is where I think my problem is?

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProRegistration regInfo = new ProRegistration();

    regInfo.TeamName = this.txtTeamName.Text.ToString();
    regInfo.ContactName = this.txtContactName.Text.ToString();
    regInfo.StreetAddress = this.txtContactAddress.Text.ToString();
    regInfo.City = this.txtContactCity.Text.ToString();
    regInfo.State = this.txtContactState.Text.ToString();
    regInfo.ZipCode = this.txtContactZip.Text.ToString();
    regInfo.Email = this.txtContactEmail.Text.ToString();
    regInfo.Phone = this.txtContactPhone.Text.ToString();
    regInfo.IsRibs = this.chkRibs.Checked;
    regInfo.IsChicken = this.chkChicken.Checked;
    regInfo.IsBrisket = this.chkBrisket.Checked;
    regInfo.IsPork = this.chkPork.Checked;
    regInfo.IsAnythingBut = this.chkAnythingBut.Checked;
    regInfo.Created = DateTime.Now;

    DataManager.InsertProfessionalRegistration(regInfo);
}
```

...So basically what I need is to be able to get a positive response when I try to submit this object to my database. Currently, no matter the click status, I get a false result.

I have been trying to research an answer to this for about 3 hours now to no avail.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know bootstrap but it looks like you are injecting an html checkbox into the output. If this is the case it will not be recognized as a server control on postback, however you can get its value by using the request.form object.

```
string result=Request.Form["thecheckboxid"];
```

Comment: Would you have a suggestion as to how I could convert my output so that I could correctly use my control during postback? That is more of my desired outcome!  Thanks!